# Session doesnt have value on laravel 4

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4, flash-message

I was wondering why is it that my when I

```
Session::flash('status', 'success');
```

and when I try to echo its value like

```
$status = Session::get('status');
dd($status);
```

Im getting a NULL value.

my controller:

```
Session::flash('status','success');
Session::flash('message', Lang::get('alerts.messages.successUpdate'));
Session::flash('type', Lang::get('alerts.transactions.po'));

return Redirect::action('SuppliersController@show',$supplierId);
```

my macro:

```
<?php
HTML::macro('flash', function()
{
$message    = Session::get('message');
$status     = Session::get('status');
$type       = Session::get('type');
return ($message) ? '<div class="alert alert-'.$status.'"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a><p>'.$message.' '.$type.'</p></div>':''; });
  ?>
```

my view:

```
<?php echo HTML::flash(); ?>
```

All variables contains the correct value except for the `$status` which is `NULL`

Is there anything I am missing on my code? Or do I always need to get the flash value from the lang folder? And cant I just declare its value on the second parameter?

Comment: Are you trying to read the session on the same request or the next request?

Comment: Hi @TamasPap Im going to read the session on the next request, is there any difference?

Comment: Are you sure there doesn't exists a line of code reading the session before `$message_status = Session::get('key');` so it is removed from the 'flash`? Just an idea.

Comment: I edited my post above and added my controller, view and my macro! thanks :)

Comment: This would be strange, but can you test what happen if you rename `status` to `status_name` or whatever? :) Does the same happening?

Comment: yeah I already tried renaming it, even with passing the same value like `Session::flash('status_name',Lang::get('alerts.messages.successUpdate'));
 Session::flash('message', Lang::get('alerts.messages.successUpdate'));` Im still getting a null result when I `dd($status_name)` any idea?

Comment: Ok, can you do a `print_r(Session::all())` before `$message    = Session::get('message');` in the macro, to see if at that moment the value is in there?

Comment: I did what you suggested, and there is no `status_name' on my flash old array list, heres the result `[login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc] => 1
    [message] => successfully create a new 
    [type] => Purchase Order` I dont really know whats happening here, but I clearly declared on my controller the `status_name` :/ im really confused right now!

Comment: Post the contents of `SuppliersController@show` method.  You're going to an action, not returning a view, so that method is relevant here.

Comment: Hi @TamasPap I figured this one out!! It was a logical error! anyway Thank you very much for your time and help! I really Appreciate it! Have a Nice Day and God Bless!

Comment: @melvnberd you should post the answer on here.. maybe it will be helpful for someone else..

Comment: Your welcome! :) Glad you resolved it!

Comment: Hi @msturdy actually the problem was not in the code. I didnt know what am I thinking because I was declaring the session part on my update method and I was testing the store method, naturally it would not affect other methods thats why its not passing any value. It was my pure recklessness thats causing the error! I am really sorry about that.. but I did learn alot of new ways from the comment and Im really thankful for all of you who helped me! :) next time Ill really should go to the obvious reasons first before digging to a more complicated one.  Have a Nice day and God Bless!